# Распарсить multipart/form-data в массив файлов и данных для теста Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Я хочу написать PHPUnit-тесты для кучи форм, которые достались по-наследству. Поэтому решение должно быть серийным.

Что получилось сделать.

1. Я заполняю и отправляю форму на сайте
2. В консоли браузера делаю "копировать как curl"
3. Полученные данные я использую для написания PHPUnit-теста в Laravel

Вот минимальный рабочий пример:

```
public function testMinimal(): void
{
    $headers = [
        "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept" => "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
    ];

    $data = "form%5Bkey%5D=val"; // данные берутся из "скопировать как curl"
    parse_str($data, $request); // это ["form[key]" => "val"]

    $resp = $this->post("test", $request, $headers);
    $resp->assertOk()->assertJson([
        "form" => ["key" => "val"]
    ]);
}
```

api.php:

```
Route::post("test", function () {
    // эхо-сервер возвращает то, что пришло
    return response(app("request")->toArray())->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
});
```

Я это сделал для форм `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. А вот с `multipart/form-data` возникла проблема - нет подходящего метода в Laravel. Я хочу что-то типа

```
$boundary = "---------------------------134321616315313667391972112742";
$body = "-----------------------------134321616315313667391972112742\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name ..."; // тут я обрезал
$resp = $this->postMultipart("test", $body, $boundary, $headers);
```

Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Наверное, [вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281614/how-to-test-file-upload-with-laravel-and-phpunit). Создаете файковое хранилище и оттуда берете файлы через UploadedFile

Comment: Такой способ мне не подходит, форм очень много, парсить и раскладывать по файлам - накладно. Также нужно в этом случае парсить параметры, их может быть очень очень много. Мне нужно серийное решение - скопировал пример запроса - вставил - написал тест

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал то, что хотел. Нужно:

1. Распарсить `multipart/form-data` с помощью пакета `riverline/multipart-parser` на части
2. Пройтись по частям и преобразовать в массив, который поддерживается Laravel

Важно замечание. Оказалось, что "копировать как cURL" не сохраняет содержимое загружаемых файлов, и нужно копировать из вкладки "Запрос". Сам запрос выглядит так:

```
-----------------------------15879248054246973702996273273
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="feedback[text]"

text
-----------------------------15879248054246973702996273273
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="feedback[file_1]"; filename="file.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

content of the file...

-----------------------------15879248054246973702996273273
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="is_draft"

true
-----------------------------15879248054246973702996273273--
```

Большие файлы таким способом скопировать не получится, браузер пишет что запрос был усечен. В этом случае можно сохранить сырой запрос на веб-сервере или пробовать на файлах ~100 Кб.

Ниже написал, как можно организовать такое тестирование.

Установить пакет: `composer require --dev riverline/multipart-parser`

Класс для преобразования `multipart/form-data` в массив для теста - файл `MultipartFormDataParser.php`:

```
namespace Tests\TestCase\MultipartFormDataParser;

use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Riverline\MultiPartParser\Converters\PSR7;
use Riverline\MultiPartParser\StreamedPart;

class MultipartFormDataParser
{
    private array $headers;
    private string $body;
    private Request $request;
    private StreamedPart $parts;
    private array $data;

    public function setHeaders(array $headers): self
    {
        $this->headers = $headers;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHeaders(): array
    {
        return $this->headers;
    }

    public function setBody(string $body): self
    {
        $this->body = $body;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getData(): array
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function guessBoundary(): self
    {
        $firstString = strtok($this->body, "\n");
        $boundary = Str::replaceFirst("--", "", $firstString);
        $this->headers = array_filter($this->headers, fn($o) => Str::lower($o) !== "content-type", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
        $this->headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary";
        return $this;
    }

    public function parse(): self
    {
        $this->request = new Request("POST", "http://localhost", $this->headers, $this->body);
        $this->parts = PSR7::convert($this->request);
        $this->data = [];

        foreach ($this->parts->getParts() as $part) {

            if ($part->isFile()) {
                $item = UploadedFile::fake()->createWithContent($part->getFileName(), $part->getBody());
                $item->mimeType($part->getMimeType());
            } else {
                $item = $part->getBody();
            }

            $data = $this->parseKeyAndSetVal($part->getName(), $item);
            $this->data = array_merge_recursive($this->data, $data);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    private function parseKeyAndSetVal($key, $val): array
    {
        parse_str($key, $res);
        array_walk_recursive($res, function (&$child) use ($val) {
            if ($child === "") {
                $child = $val;
            }
        }, $val);
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Тест `MinTest.php`, в котором используется парсер:

```
class MinTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testMin(): void
    {
        $headers = [
            // Заголовок Content-Type будет заменен в guessBoundary(), он тут не обязателен
            "Content-Type" => "multipart/form-data; boundary=guess-boundary",
            "Accept" => "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
        ];

        $body = "..."; // тут body запроса, взято из dev tools браузера, сеть, вкладка "Запрос"

        $parser = new MultipartFormDataParser;
        $parser->setHeaders($headers)->setBody($body)->guessBoundary()->parse();
        $data = $parser->getData();
        $resp = $this->post("test", $data, $parser->getHeaders());
        dd($resp->json());
    }
}
```

Эхо-сервер для проверки:

```
Route::post("test", function () {
    // эхо-сервер возвращает то, что пришло
    /** @var \Illuminate\Http\Request $request */
    $request = app("request");
    return response([
        "data" => $request->post(),
        "files" => array_keys($request->allFiles())
    ])->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
});
```